Upgraded ubuntu, now bootup takes longer
On startup, the system starts looking for 3 drives/partitions which it will never find within it's 2 minutes and 30 seconds of waiting time. In the previous version, the boot time was super fast, but now i have to wait multiple minutes for it to finish booting. Please help, if you know what is going on.
Also, sorry for the quality of the pictures.



EDIT:
In response to the comments below:

Maybe if i comment out the problematic disks it'll work?

The 3 disks that caused problems are commented out on the image above. They are 2-3 lines before the end of the file.

It's waiting for a disk to come online, but the disk doesn't show up. Is there a disk in your /etc/fstab that has disappeared from the system?

What Jos said, useful commands to understand what's going on (please post the output of both if you need help): lsblk -o NAME,UUID and sudo cat /etc/fstab

Use lsblk, or take a look at /etc/fastab and check what those partitions where supposed to be, probably you have dual-boot with Windows installed and they're 'bit-locked' and therefore are not being able to be mounted. Maybe if you reboot into windows and disable that  or 'Fast Boot' and reboot your computer normally it will work. If it is not your case or it does not work, try commenting them from fstab and things shall work properly.
Another thing you can do is try to mount them manually and check what they are or have inside, it will make it easier to debug.
